# Is it possible to create "desktop shortcuts" on motif window manager (mwm)

Tags: window-manager, motif

I am trying to use MWM, however I cannot figure out how to make icon shortcuts.

I have created an icon box, but it only collects minimized windows that were already started before.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/x-window-system/9780937175149/ChapterC.html

[image: Shows my current window]

Does anyone have a way of creating a shortcut, like *.desktop on ubuntu but for mwm, to launch a script?

EDIT:

These are the books I have looked at.

https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/motif/vol6a/Vol6a.pdf (pg 596) - Shows how to create an app box, which i guess could be used as a start menu.
http://www.whigg.cas.cn/resource/zysk/201011/P020101102761806071794.pdf

Comment: Have you gone thru the [documentation](https://motif.ics.com/support/docs/documentation)?  Since this WM is not included with any Ubuntu distro, you might have better luck using the [tech support](https://motif.ics.com/support) options provided by the developers of this software.

Comment: Note that, although mwm is not present by default on any freshly installed Ubuntu system, it is packaged for Ubuntu and [available from Ubuntu's repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mwm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). In that way, it is like many programs people get good answers about here. With that said, I can't really speak to where the *best* place is to ask about it. With *that* said, I also don't know the details of which support options elsewhere would cover mwm if it is installed from downstream Ubuntu packages, as it typically would be on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: Thank you. I will look through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I have not done it in years. I still use MWM for applications servers and launch the applications at start. I like MWM for single applications servers in that all the shinny objects are not there for operations to play with that are present in other windows managers like gnome. It saves a lot of support calls in the middle of the night. In case the operators need to restart the applications or close the xterm application I create a menu entry in the ~/.mwmrc file. So all the operator has to do is right click the screen and select the menu entry to launch. It is much simpler then creating ICONs and gets the same job done.